# Formulas for the constants in fdlibm/e_pow.c

Tags: c, math, floating-point

I'm trying to understand the implementation of power function in [fdlibm/e_pow.c](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c).  Does anyone know how the constants were computed?  In particular, I need the formulas for `dp_h[]`, `dp_l[]`, `L1`, `L2`, `L3`, `L4`, `L5`, `L6`, `P1`, `P2`, `P3`, `P4`, `P5`, `lg2`, `lg2_l`, `ovt`, `cp_l` (what's tail?).

Also, the equation given is missing a parenthesis.  Is it supposed to be [(3/2)*(log(x)-2s-2/3*s**3)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3/2%2a%20%28log%28x%29-2s-2/3%2as%2a%2a3%29)?

Comment: While an entirely fascinating question, it probably belongs on Math.SE.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: it's explicitly and clearly about programming.  Why on earth would it belong on math?

Comment: Constants in a mathematical algorithm are chosen because they're relevant mathematically. If that isn't about math then I'll eat my own shoes.

Comment: Of course it's about math; it's also about programming.  Those constants are chosen not only for their mathematical properties, but also because they satisfy certain requirements that apply only to implementation of the algorithm in question on a physical computer (i.e. programming); as it happens those considerations turn out to be more interesting than the mathematical ones, which are simple to understand.  Are we going to start deleting any question relating to e-commerce because "it's about sales"?

Comment: This question hits **all** four of the topics stated in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): Implementing `pow` is a specific programming problem, it is a software algorithm, `pow` and its sources are tools widely used by programmers, and the questions asked are practical, answerable problems unique to the programming question. Most of the constants used are of no particular general mathematical value; it is **only** their function in implementing `pow` that makes them interesting.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: No, the constants in `pow` are not chosen because they are relevant mathematically. The head-tail representations are chosen because of specifics of the floating-point implementation, not general mathematical principles. The minimax polynomial is **designed** for a particular implementation, not a general mathematical function. `pow` implementations are **engineered** for specific platforms and features, not purely derived from mathematical principles. Designing them is hard and is a deep software problem.

Comment: See meta discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161986

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of this is based on a very cursory examination of the linked source:

`dp_h` and `dp_l` are the high and low adjustment terms that are either added or not (depending on the array index that is used to load them) depending on which portion of the binade the reduced argument lies in.

`Ln` and `Pn` are coefficients for polynomial approximations to exponential and logarithmic functions, respectively.  It's hard to say for sure without a more careful examination, but from a glance at the coefficients, they appear to be minimax approximations, which are would typically be calculated using the Remes exchange algorithm.

`lg2`, `lg2_h` and `lg2_l` are approximations to log(2) -- respectively they are log(2) rounded to double, rounded to 21 bits, and the residual of rounding to 21 bits rounded to a double.

`ovt` is, I think, short for OVerflow Threshold and is used to determine whether or not the result overflows before computing the exponential part of the algorithm.  One would need to examine the details of the algorithm more carefully to explain precisely how it is derived.

`cp_h` and `cp_l` together form a head-tail approximation to 2/(3*log2).

"tail" is a common term in math library design; often a library needs to represent constants to higher precision than can be done using a single floating-point value.  So the constant is represented as "head + tail" where "head" is the value rounded to some number of bits, and "tail" is constant - head rounded to the data type.

If you're unfamiliar with this sort of basic terminology, then you probably want to start by looking at some math library functions that are simpler than pow( ); it's one of the most mathematically complex functions in the library.  I would also recommend looking at at Muller et al's [Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-0-8176-4704-9) for an introduction.